# python conversion to integer in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, int

How do I convert `{'CS2261': '140', 'CS3264': '55'}` to `{'CS2261': 140, 'CS3264': 55}`?

```
def everything(file):
    a = {}
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for i in f:
            Module,Group,Quota = i.split(',')
            if Module not in a:
                a[Module] = int(Quota)
        return a
```

Comment: You are asking about *converting* a dictionary, but then post a code sample that *builds* a dictionary. What is the exact problem with the `everything()` function and what is its relationship to the first sentence?

Answer (score 1):

You can reconstruct the dictionary with dictionary comprehension like this

```
d = {'CS2261': '140', 'CS3264': '55'}
print {k: int(d[k]) for k in d}
# {'CS3264': 55, 'CS2261': 140}
```

Comment: Hang your head in shame for not using `k,v in d.items()` (+1)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget In Python 2.7, it has to create another list. So, I don't prefer that :)

Comment: fine, `d.iteritems()`, then

Comment: @inspectorG4dget And it will not work in Python 3.x :)

Comment: fine, if you're going for over backwards portability

Answer (score 1):

```
{k:int(v) for k,v in d.items()}
```

Comment: Or for large dictionaries in python 2, `.iteritems()`